# What does speed of issuance of SSL Certificate mean?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

How does speed of issuance effect my site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simply a metric that relates to how long you must wait before the certificate is in your hands after you have applied for one.

An issuer of a basic certificate that just performs email domain checks can do it quickly, an issuer of a certificate with extended validation ("Green bar" EV-SSL certs etc.) takes longer as they run additional identity checks.

It does not affect your website in any way unless you fail to plan for the issuance period when renewing.

Comment: is the following SSL ok for a new E Commerce site? As i need a cost effective certificate, i could find this. Please give your valued response. http://www.instantssl.com/ssl-certificate-products/addsupport/ssl-instantssl_pro.html?whichssl

Answer (score 0):

It is how quickly you can expect to get your certificate after requesting it.  Certificate providers validate your business before issuing a certificate and this is what takes time. It won't affect the users of your site.